# Group by min value. Why does my solution fail?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with ids of points on a cartesian plot and the distances between them.

I'm trying to find the nearest neighbor for each point (designated by id). So, i'm looking for minimum distance.

Table distances:

```
id1 id2 distance
1   2   2
1   3   5
1   4   2.23606797749979
2   1   2
2   3   3.605551275463989
2   4   1
3   1   5
3   2   3.605551275463989
3   4   2.8284271247461903
4   1   2.23606797749979
4   2   1
4   3   2.8284271247461903
```

The expected output is:

```
id1 id2 distance
1   2   2
2   4   1
3   4   2.8284271247461903
4   2   1
```

My solution fails because I think i'm not understanding something fundamental about how 'group by' works.

```
SELECT id1, id2, MIN(distance) AS distance from distances
GROUP BY id1
ORDER BY id1 ASC;
```

My output:

```
id1 id2 distance
1   2   2
2   1   1
3   1   2.8284271247461903
4   1   1
```

**Why does my solution fail, and what is the appropriate solution?**

Comment: Hint: this is the most frequently asked question under this tag

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current query is that you are telling MySQL to return *one* record for each `id1` group, by you do not have any logic telling it which value of `id2` to choose.  Logically speaking, MySQL is free to return any such record it wishes.

To fix this, you may try either of the following two approaches.  On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY distance) rn
    FROM distances
)

SELECT id1, id2, distance
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can join to a subquery which finds the smallest distance for each `id1` group:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM distances d1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id1, MIN(distance) AS min_distance
    FROM distances
    GROUP BY id1
) d2
    ON d1.id1 = d2.id1 AND
       d1.distance = d2.min_distance;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making an assumption that because you requested the MIN(), that the other column `id2` will naturally be reported from the same line where the MIN() value was found. This is not how GROUP BY works.

What if more than one row tied for the minimum distance? Which value of `id2` should be reported?

What if you requested both MIN() distance and MAX() distance? Which value of `id2` should be reported?

What if you were requesting AVG() instead of MIN(), and *no* single row had the average value?

Please search answers to questions with the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag. This type of question has been answered many times (the same kinds of solutions apply when you want the row with the least value per group).

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL should generate an error, since you have included id1 and id2 outside of any aggregate functions, and id2 is outside of the 'group by' statement.

You need to consider two steps. Firstly what is the minimum distance, and secondly which row returns the minimum distance. Let's ignore the possibility initially that there are multiple equidistant rows.

So:

```
    SELECT id1, MIN(distance) AS distance from distances
    GROUP BY id1;
```

Having determined the minimum distance, you need to get the row where this occurs

```
    SELECT d.id1, d.id2, d.distance
    from distances d
    join (SELECT id1, MIN(distance) AS distance from distances
    GROUP BY id1) a on a.id1 = d.id1 and a.distance = d.distance;
```

This will return all rows where the distance is the minimum, which may include more than one per id1. You can modify this by adding a grouping column to id2 on the outer query (max, min etc) if needed.